# Changing part of the name of the function

Tags: function-construction

Is it possible in Mathematica to replace the part of the name of the function to give the same arguments to another function?
In fact, I have a lot of functions with the following name pattern:

```
function$1234[x,y,z]
function$2345[x,y,z]
function$6423[x,y,z]
```

and I want to replace the number part to substitute x,y, and z in all of the functions.

I do not want to give these numbers as normal arguments due to clarity.

As far as I know from other languages I should do something like StringReplace but is there any better way to do this?

Comment: ``Names["Global`function$" ~~ DigitCharacter ..] /. fn_String :> Symbol[fn][x, y, z]``?

Comment: You can always define functions like `function[1][x, y, z]`, `function[2][x, y, z]`, etc.

Comment: If you have a number like `6423` you can get the function name with something like ```template = StringTemplate["function$``"]; Symbol[template[6423]] ```

Answer (score 1):

The following example should get you there. Just change the regular expression and the evaluation point.

```
Clear[f1, f2, f3]
f1[x_, y_, z_] := x*y*z
f2[x_, y_, z_] := x*y*z^2
f3[x_, y_, z_] := x*y*z^3
funcs = ToExpression /@ Names[RegularExpression["f[0-9]"]] (* the functions *)
Through[funcs[1, 2, 3]]  (* evaluate at a common point *)
```